# How to read XML data from api request

Tags: php, xml

I am making a call to some url : `http://example.com/Service.asmx/getTodaysDiscussionForum` which is xml data please see screenshot :[image]

```
$response = file_get_contents('http://103.1.115.87:100/Service.asmx/getTodaysDiscussionForum');

$response = new SimpleXMLElement($response);

print_r($response);exit;
```

it display following output :

```
SimpleXMLElement Object ( 
         [Table1] => Array ( [0] => SimpleXMLElement Object ( 
                                      [Id] => 1210 [Title] => Test Discussion, Dont Reply [CreatedDate] => 4/25/2014 10:42:49 AM 
                                      [Status] => Not Sent ) 
                             [1] => SimpleXMLElement Object ( 
                                      [Id] => 1182 [Title] => Negotiation Skills discussion [CreatedDate] => 4/25/2014 7:47:51 AM 
                                      [Status] => Not Sent )
                           )  
                        )
```

How can I store each data in a variables ?

I am new to this xml reading thanks in advance

Comment: It is not clear what part of the XML you need to access. You are already using SimpleXML, so can access the contents in various ways, as [demonstrated in the manual](http://php.net/manual/en/simplexml.examples-basic.php). If you are having a problem accessing a particular part of the document, edit your question or ask a new one to clarify exactly what the problem is.

Comment: Also, an image is not a good way of showing XML code; just paste it as text into the question, highlight it, and click the `{}` button to mark it as code. That way, people can copy and paste it into their own examples.

Comment: @IMSoP dude I already got my answer which I marked as accepted already and people here understood my question and this question is 3 month older.

Comment: downvoters please explain why ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$xml = simplexml_load_string($xmlstring);
$json = json_encode($xml); 
$array = json_decode($json,TRUE);
```

Comment: Ill try this and let you know

Comment: This is a horrible horrible approach, and a complete waste of SimpleXML's abilities.

Comment: Well there is an abbreviation KISS , which means **Keep It Simple and Stupid**. So according to me working with array is simpler than working with xml. If you call it stupid , I will take it as a complement.

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php

foreach($response[0] as $data) {
        $id = $data->Id;
        //...
}
```

Comment: thank for reply, i have tried this but when i try to print_r($data) inside loop it shows SimpleXMLElement Object ( [Id] => 1214 [Title] => Test Discussion, Dont Reply anybody [CreatedDate] => 4/25/2014 10:51:28 AM [Status] => Not Sent ) SimpleXMLElement Object ( [Id] => 1182 [Title] => Negotiation Skills discussion [CreatedDate] => 4/25/2014 7:47:51 AM [Status] => Not Sent ) but when i try $id = $data->Id; it does not show anything

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php

 $requestUrl = 'https://example/sitemap.xml';

 $response = file_get_contents($requestUrl);

 $responseXml = simplexml_load_string($response);
 foreach ($responseXml->Table1 as $Table1) {
 echo $Table1->Title;
 echo "<br>";
}

?>
```