# How to traverse XML tree with PHP's SimpleXML extension?

Tags: php, xml, simplexml

Given the following XML:

```
$xmlstr = <<<XML
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<soap:Envelope xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
  <soap:Body>
    <DataService xmlns="http://www.example.com">
      <Response>
        <XMLRootNode xmlns="http://www.example.com">
          <ResponseHeader>
            <Version>2.0</Version>
            <RecordCount>2</RecordCount>
          </ResponseHeader>
          <OnlineInformation BoothID="12345">
            <EventID>4</EventID>
            ...
```

How can I access the contents of `EventID` using PHP's SimpleXML extension? I've had success with a simple example form [here](http://www.php.net/manual/en/simplexml.examples-basic.php), but I cannot seem to traverse the more complex tree structure above. My basic code is below. I want `$output` to contain the value 4.

```
$data = new SimpleXMLElement($xmlstr);

$output = $data->...
```

Thanks.

Comment: try doing a print_r($data) then you can figure out how your data is organized in that object.

Comment: It's better to `var_dump($data)`, as `$data` is an object.

Comment: Intuitively: `$output = $data->{'soap:Body'}->DataService->Response->XMLRootNode->OnlineInformation->EventID;` looks right to me, but it throws an error 'Trying to get property of non-object'.

Comment: or maybe [convert the xml to json format](http://stackoverflow.com/a/23291095/3419997) , if you find json easy.

Comment: @sumit No, please please don't do that. You're basically throwing away all the useful functionality that SimpleXML provides, and producing a poorly formatted array which will be much harder to work with.

Comment: Your "basic code" is basically no code at all, which makes this seem suspiciously like you just want us to write your code for you. Is there a specific problem you are stuck on and would like help with?

Answer (score 0):

You can alternatively you `DOMDocument`. Like this:

```
// your incomplete xml sample
$xmlstr = <<<XML
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
  <soap:Envelope xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
    <soap:Body>
      <DataService xmlns="http://www.example.com">
        <Response>
          <XMLRootNode xmlns="http://www.example2.com">
            <ResponseHeader>
              <Version>2.0</Version>
              <RecordCount>2</RecordCount>
            </ResponseHeader>
            <OnlineInformation ExampleID="12345">
              <EventID>4</EventID>
            </OnlineInformation>
          </XMLRootNode>    
        </Response>
      </DataService>
    </soap:Body>
  </soap:Envelope>
XML;

$dom = new DOMDocument();
$dom->loadXML($xmlstr);
foreach($dom->getElementsByTagName('OnlineInformation') as $OnlineInformation) {
    if($OnlineInformation->getAttribute('ExampleID') == 12345) {
        echo $OnlineInformation->getElementsByTagName('EventID')->item(0)->nodeValue;
        // 4
    }
}
```

Or just use `xpath` and directly point it:

```
$xml = simplexml_load_string($xmlstr);
$xml->registerXPathNamespace('ns', 'http://www.example2.com');
$node = $xml->xpath('//ns:OnlineInformation[@ExampleID="12345"]')[0];
echo (string) $node->EventID; // 4
```

Comment: Thanks, this gave me some ideas to follow up on.